# Should I say "A is more fun than B" or "A is of more fun than B"?

Tags: word-choice

I am a bit confused with the word `fun`.

I want to express that doing A will be more happy than doing B.

I don't want to mislead to my reader that doing A is more funny or hilarious.

Which sentence should I choose?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "of" is not correct here; your first version is the right one.

There is rarely any confusion for English speakers between "fun" and "funny".

Comment: If A were more amusing it would be _funnier_ than B.